# How do (if) the relative paces of time differ in these circular motions?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, orbital-motion, time-dilation, string

I) Imagine two equal masses tied tethered together by a rope in empty space. The rotate around their COM in the middle of the rope. The masses don't cause gravity.
The masses don't move wrt one another. If you look to one mass from another then both masses are stationary (somewhat like Webb being stationary at L2).
It's my guess that both observers see the clock on the other mass have the same pace as their own. But for a distant observer in an inertial frame, both clocks seem to go slower because their relative velocities wrt this observer.
But there is also a force felt by the masses. They appear, in a co-rotating frame, to be in a gravitational field (equivalence principle).
And in a gravitational field, fixed in a point in it, time goes slower that in a faraway position where gravity is zero. Though you can also position the observer in the center of the circular motion (or is there a difference then, as seen from the co-rotating frames?).
Altogether it seems that the clocks on the masses go slower because of the two effects. Both cause time to go slower.

II) Now imagine the same masses without a rope but circling around each other by means of gravity. In free fall. Well, of course the masses can't be the same because then a rope wouldn't be needed in the first example. So the masses are equal and much bigger than they were.
The situation is comparable, but obviously different. There are no forces felt (ignoring tidal forces).
Seen from both masses the other is stationary. But this time no artificial gravity dilates time. For a distant observer (I think this time it matters where to put the faraway observer, because in the center their time goes different than at infinity) very far away, both clocks will again experience dilation because of the relative velocities and on top the dilation because the masses reside in each other's g-field.

If all clocks in both examples are magically brought together, it's obvious that the faraway observers have equal times.
But what about the other four? Do all four read the same time (but earlier than the faraway observer's). Will they all read the same?

I don't really see the practical use, but it's interesting.

Comment: With gravity they follow a geodesic. With ropes they don't. If you analyze the difference carefully you will get consistent answers.

Comment: Instead of having two large masses orbiting their common center of gravity, would it be acceptable to have two small masses orbiting a large central mass? The issue is that the problem as you have described it has no analytical solution and would require a numerical solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity